# Change directory to last match in *nix cd command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, cd

```
./
  folder_1
  folder_2
  folder_3
  ...
  folder_46
```

For first match -> **cd folder_*** -> folder_1

But what to do for last match (folder_46)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd `ls -rd folder_*`
```

There is always a shorter code :)

Comment: Frankly, I have to warn you: this will work in most cases. It will fail though, if the list of files becomes too long. In this sense a `cd $(ls -rd folder_*|head -1)` is safer. It is also less cool, so I didn't write it in the answer.

Comment: `ls | head` won't safe from `too many arguments` error, because it occurs firstly with `ls` and `ls` will die. `cd` won't see any dir name.

Comment: Eh, right. Still, the shortest command, even if not always applicable... Wait, how about: `cd $(ls -rd|grep ^folder_|head -1)`?

Comment: @RobDavis it wont even start: the command line will become too long because of globbing producing too many files

Comment: @RobDavis Maybe, but rush _was_ talking about my example, and it looks like you were complaining that he was wrong. He wasn't, of course, if you see his example in the context

Comment: Yes, but you have torn it out of context. No one would disagree with you about `ls|head` being safe from `too many arguments`. But, it wasn't his point, and I did understand what he was talking about, and what his point really was.

Comment: My bad. I misread the whole thing and didn't realize you were globbing the arguments to `ls`! Tired brain. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, nothing a cup o'coffee can't help with

Answer (score 2):

`ls` isn't suited for this type of use. You can use file globbing and an array:

```
dirs=(folder_*/); cd "${dirs[@]: -1}"
```

The glob is guaranteed to be expanded in lexical order. The array slice accesses the last member of the array.

You could create a function that would automatically remove the array:

```
cdl () { declare -a dirs=(${1:-folder_}*/); cd "${dirs[@]: -1}"; }
```

This defaults to a prefix of "folder_", but it will accept an argument to use another prefix:

```
cdl dirname-
```

`declare` inside a function makes the variable local to the function.

If you're using Bash 4.2, you can access the last array element directly instead of using a slice as above:

```
cd "${dirs[-1]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

> cd `ls -ld folder_* | awk '{print $9}' | sort | sed -e '$!d'`

But I guess you'll have to name your folders folder_01, folder_02 instead of folder_1, folder_2, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
cd $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "folder_*" | sort -t_ -k2 -n -r | head -1)
```

that will work even in case there are too many directories (`ls` will die with `too many arguments` error. and it works with `folder_1` .. `folder_[any_number]`. you don't need to rename `folder_1` to `folder_01` or `folder_001` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
cdlast() { cd "${!#}"; }

cdlast folder_*
```